# Multiple Python Flask sites on IIS

Tags: python, asp.net, iis, flask

I want to run three separate Python Flask URLS, let's call them test, staging, and production. I want one IIS website to serve up these three different applications.

So I have created a website, created three IIS Applications under this site, and set the root folders for these to d:\execution\test, d:\execution\staging, d:\execution\prod respectively.

Under each of these folders is a hello_world.py that looks like this

```
import datetime
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World (Test)!' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Obviously with the route changed to /test, /staging and /prod as needed
Each folder also contains a web.config that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="hello_world.py" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />       
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <identity impersonate="false" />
    </system.web>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\Execution\Test" />
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="hello_world.app" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Again with the PYTHONPATH changed as required

The main website root has a web.config in that says

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="Python Flask" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Python34\python.exe|C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is the python handler. If I take this out, I can serve up basic HTML pages fine from the websites and the three application sub-folder/URLs. If I put it back in, I can't get anything, not even just a basic HTML page. IIS throws a generic "The webpage cannot be found. HTTP 404 Not Found" when I try to navigate to anything, be it directory browsing, an index.html or the http://server:port/test app route as mentioned above for my python flask app.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you ever deployed a singular python app to this instance of IIS?  If you complete the following tutorial, you should be able to isolate whether your issue lies in your application or in your server configuration: [kb276494](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/276494) That shouldn't take too long to confirm and will help you build up to finding your root cause.

Comment: Did you enable CGI when you installed IIS? [flask on IIS tutorial](http://netdot.co/2015/03/09/flask-on-iis/)

Comment: I have yes, I have a singular one on the same IIS server which seems to work fine, just named a different website

Comment: so if you disable the bindings for the "staging" and "production" sites, you can get the "/test" route to serve?

Comment: Stranger. I stop and start w3svc, kill inetinfo.exe, restart the website, then browse to one of the three applications. The application is called PFTest and the route mapped in python is /test. Initially it comes up as http://site/PFTest and cant find anything but if I then navigate manually to http://site/test it works. But the same then doesn't work for the other two applications. If I restart everything again and select a different application first, it works. So it seems after a fresh restart, the first application I try and browse to works, but then the other two dont

Comment: It is all one site, so they have the same binding, they are just three different applications under the one site

Comment: And if after a restart I navigate straight to http://site/test it fails, without the web.config variables initialised. I have to navigate to the /PFTest application first, have it fail, it obviously then initialises and allows me to then use the /test route. But it fails to do the same for the other two applications

Comment: Sorry for having to bail on you before you're able to get this straightened out, but I'll check back in later.  Check these over to see if they can get you moving:  [python wsgi apps on iis](http://taoofmac.com/space/blog/2016/03/20/2330) | [running flask apps on local iis](https://heejune.me/2015/04/22/running-python-flask-on-a-local-iis-not-azure-with-wfastcgi-py/)

Comment: Ok thanks will take a look

Comment: AH!  I just realized your `wfast*gi.py` at the site level has a `c` in it but your handler defined at the app level is a WSGI_Handler. That won't work. CGI uses environment variables at the site level to determine what to load into each of the processes that it spawns.

Comment: I thought WFastCGI was just one way to implement WSGI?

Comment: yes, you can implement wsgi over cgi, but I suspect that your cgi driver is not playing nicely with multiple applications inside the same site activation context. The behavior you described indicates that the driver is expecting a globally scoped application and is not allowing you to swap out which app will be activated by http.sys

Answer (score 0):

I think the root of your problem lies in the fact that your site has a `CGI`based handler specified that is going to override the `wsgi_handler` values that you provide for each of your applications.

..are you really intending to run wsgi over cgi? 
If your answer is no, then that definitely could be your problem.

Comment: The root of my problem might be that I actually don't know the difference between the two. Is it quite a major thing? I think I'd better do some reading up

Comment: @NZJames certainly, you can implement the wsgi contract over cgi, but I think what is happening here is that the cgi driver you are using (or the way you have configured it) is expecting your appdomain to contain exactly 1 application. CGI typically operates via environment variables, and the behavior you described in one of your comments seems to indicate to me that your cgi driver has no reference to your application root until you attempt to activate it manually, then that application gets loaded into the env and is not switching out whenever you attempt to activate a different app.

Comment: @NZJames I was going to try to complete the task of deploying 2 flask apps directly to IIS last night so that I could provide a detailed description of how to make it work, but "life."  ...I'll try to get it finished this weekend so that you can move on.

Comment: @NZJames In retrospect, I'm likely barking up the wrong tree with a mentioning of wsgi and wfastcgi. Pretty much "everyone" uses wfastcgi for deploying Python applications to IIS.

Comment: Thanks for helping out Alan, really appreciate it. For now I have them in three separate websites which works as you can have separate configs that way. Did you get any joy getting multiple sites working? Also just a small aside, do you know how to pass a parameter through to the wfastcgi script? I wanted to pass a parameter to my entry point python script but can't seem to see how to do it.

Comment: @NZJames Did you have any luck with this later on? I'm struggling with the exact same issue today.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I have a similar problem and found a solution which may help people using Flask + IIS:

Solution: Use blueprints... Each application should set the blueprint URL including the name of the Virtual Directory (Application)

For example if you have the following structure on IIS:

```
DefaultWebSite
   \YourFlaskApp01
   \YourFlaskApp02
   ...
```

On YourFlaskApp01 code set a Flask Blueprint:

```
bpname = flask.Blueprint('bpname', __name__, url_prefix='/YourFlaskApp01')
```

On YourFlaskApp02 code set a Flask Blueprint:

```
bpname = flask.Blueprint('bpname', __name__, url_prefix='/YourFlaskApp02')
```

And use the blue prints on your endpoint methods:

```
@bpname.route("/foo", methods=["GET"])
def foo():
   ...
```

If you are not using blueprints I guess it also works if you set the correct setting directly on

```
@app.route('/YourFlaskApp01/test')
```

But I have not tested it. :(

On IIS remember always to give appropriate permissions to the user associated to the application pool.

General instruction on setting up Flask + IIS:

[Microsoft Learn - Configure Python web apps for IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2022)

[Medium.com - Deploy a Python Flask Application in IIS Server and run on machine IP address](https://medium.com/@dpralay07/deploy-a-python-flask-application-in-iis-server-and-run-on-machine-ip-address-ddb81df8edf3)

[Flask - Modular Applications with Blueprints](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/blueprints/)

Hope this may help someone!